Dockerizing Adonisjs throw a SyntaxError
I'm trying to Dockerize Adonis following the tutorial of Adonis and the base installation :
https://v5-docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/dockerizing-adonis
https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/getting-started/installation
I'm using the basic starter :
npm init adonisjs@latest hello-world -- --db=mysql --kit=api 

The dockerfile is the same as the guide, same for the docker compose, i just don't use postgres or redis
I started a mariadb in my docker to try the app without dockerizing it, it work fine but if i try to start it using docker compose i have the SyntaxError :
file:///home/node/app/ace.js:22
import { register } from 'node:module'
         ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'node:module' does not provide an export named 'register'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:181:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)

docker-compose.yml
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: mariadb
    volumes:
      - "._mysql_data_dir/:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=xxx
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=xxx
      - MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
    restart: always

  adonis_app:
    container_name: adonis_app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      target: dependencies
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
      # Uncomment the below line if you developing on MacOS
      #- /home/node/app/node_modules
    command: dumb-init node ace serve --watch --node-args="--inspect=0.0.0.0"

Dockerfile
ARG NODE_IMAGE=node:16.13.1-alpine

FROM $NODE_IMAGE AS base
RUN apk --no-cache add dumb-init
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
USER node
RUN mkdir tmp

FROM base AS dependencies
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY --chown=node:node . .

FROM dependencies AS build
RUN node ace build --production

FROM base AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=$PORT
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --production
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /home/node/app/build .
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "dumb-init", "node", "server.js" ]


Node version : v21.6.1
I have the same error on Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10
Am i missing something ?

You have Node 21 on your host, but you're using Node 16 in your image.  Do you need a newer version of Node in the Dockerfile?  (I'd recommend deleting the volumes: block in the Compose file, otherwise pretty much everything in the Dockerfile gets ignored.)

Hi, thanks for your advices, i tried to update the version in the Dockerfile and deleted the volumes, but nothing has changed; which is weird because it's straight for the AdonisJs documentation.
I maybe can make it work using a old Dockerfile i had for a node project,
I'll keep updating the post
